# Updates to the same table in concurrent sessions in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, concurrency, dml

Consider the following scenario:

1. 10,000 users try to create a profile on our application concurrently at the same time and the data has to be inserted into the table, userProfile.
2. The SP that handles this insertion takes half a second to execute.

From my understanding of locking and transactions, this table will be locked for every insert. That means by the time the last user's profile is created it'll take a while. How does SQL Server handle concurrent updates and locking? I would appreciate any insights on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite a wide area and whole books have been written on the subject, and many short- & long-form articles have been written about specific details, so I'll just answer your specific points and hopefully give you some keywords to search on for further reading.

> From my understanding of locking and transactions, this table will be locked for every insert.

That is not true. Locks can be as small as a page or a single row, not necessarily the entire table, so concurrent activity reading other pages may still be able to continue concurrently – so the app can likely read your profile row, allowing you to login or others to view your bio, while others' profiles are being created.

Different transaction and locking options can help with concurrency of many inserts, for instance snapshot isolation will allow reads that might lock waiting for the new rows to be added (such as queries that read the whole table, though these should be rare) to complete but just seeing the committed state of the DB as their transaction started.

> 10,000 users try to create a profile … data has to be inserted into the table, userProfile.

There is a specific issue with incrementing integer indexes, often used as primary keys for such tables, which can cause contention creating many new rows: lookup “last page contention” for more information. SQL Server 2019 and above has a specific index optimisation for this, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY. Though if you are at the level of worrying about whole table locks, then you are a long way from needing to know intimate details here.

This issue should not affect other concurrent queries: as above reads that don't need to care about the last page of the indexes should not be locked out waiting for this activity to complete unless you have truly swamped the available resources of the server.

Also, will the rest of your app's infrastructure realistically support 10K concurrent requests in order to impart that load on SQL Server?! Can your web server (assuming this sort of application) accept and process that many concurrent connections, etc.

> The SP that handles this insertion takes half a second to execute.

If you are just creating a single row for the new profile, half a second is two or three orders of magnitude too high unless you are running in really really *really* old/odd hardware or using a stupendously over-sold VPS provider. It should be more like a couple of hundredths of a second or less.

If it is doing some other more complex logic along with creating that row, then careful design should allow you to minimise the length of time it holds locks on the user profile table. If the logic of that procedure is this complex though, you need to worry more about designing to reduce deadlocks than massive concurrency so perhaps simplify that procedure. Of course you could try to solve a deadlock issue naïvely by setting all your transaction's isolation levels to serialisable, but then you are creating the very problem you started worrying about (making each statement touching that table wait for the others to complete).

> How does SQL Server handle concurrent updates and locking? I would appreciate any insights on this.

[Microsoft's Learn docs on Transaction locking and row versioning guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver16) might be a good place to start general reading. If that is a bit deep for you initially, try searching around relevant keywords to find more tutorially designed descriptions and return to the drier reference material when you have a little more grounding on the basics, and of course return here when you have more specific questions.